# How Can I Install Eclipse with the ADT (Android Development Tool) on Ubuntu 11.10 64-bit?

Tags: 11.10, 64-bit, android, eclipse

There is the Android documentation:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html

And there is this WordPress blog I found:

http://bhargavg.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/installing-android-development-environment-on-ubuntu-11-10/

Neither worked for me out of the box. But by piecing together bits and pieces from other sources, I think I have managed to configure Eclipse to run with the ADT plugin. I will post a step-by-step guide here with my source.

There is also this nicely detailed step-by-step guide for Ubuntu 10.10 listed in another question that deserves mention:

http://www.futuredesktop.com/maverick/android/developing_android_apps_on_ubuntu.html

Again, I don't think the steps listed there will work for 11.10 64-bit, but it offers an excellent overview of the process in general.

Comment: I'll post my response once my newbie moratorium expires. :) In meantime, answer can be found here: http://klenwell.com/is/Pastebin20120223

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### 1. Install Java Packages

- http://softwareinabottle.wordpress.com/2011/11/17/install-sun-jdk-6-on-ubuntu-11-10/
- http://thelinuxexperiment.com/guinea-pigs/tyler-b/how-to-install-sun-java6-jdk-and-netbeans-in-ubuntu-11-10/

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk sun-java6-plugin
  ```

#### 2. Install ia32-libs

- http://android-eclipse.blogspot.com/2011/05/failed-to-get-adb-version-cannot-run.html

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
  ```

#### 3. Select Correct Version of JVM using update-alternative

(install update-alternative with apt-get if necessary)

- http://android-eclipse.blogspot.com/2011/05/failed-to-get-adb-version-cannot-run.html

  ```
  sudo update-alternatives --config java
  ```

  then select the number for: `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java`

#### 4. Install Eclipse

I installed this version as recommended by google:

- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/indigo/R/eclipse-java-indigo-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

  This is a guide for 64-bit Ubuntu, so make sure to get the 64-bit version

  Download, unzip, double-click eclipse file in root dir to launch

#### 5. Install SDK Start Package

I just followed the Android docs here:

- http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html#Installing

#### 6. Install Android Platforms

- http://bhargavg.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/installing-android-development-environment-on-ubuntu-11-10/

  Double click `android-sdk-linux/tools/android`

#### 7. Install ADT Plugin

Follow steps for downloading and configuring:

- http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

#### 8. Add these lines to bottom of .bashrc

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/8693384/1093087

  ```
  export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdks/platform-tools
  export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=~/android-sdks/platform-tools
  export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_HOME
  ```

  To edit:

  ```
  gedit ~.bashrc
  ```

  type in lines above with correct paths:

  ```
  source ~/.bashrc`
  ```

#### 9. Restart Eclipse

If successful, you should see no errors on startup and console panel will say: `Android`